# How to change a list's name in R

Tags: r

lets say i have the following code:

```
mylist <- (1,2,3)
Somelist <- (A,B,C)
```

How can I change the name of mylist itself into `Somelist[[1]]`
so that from now on i can call/modify `mylist` by using `A` instead of `mylist`.

Alternatively I wouldn't mind to find a way to use `Somelist[[1]]` as a name which I could attach to `mylist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R doesn't work with objects in the same way that some other languages, such as Python, do. For example in Python, you can create an object and give it a name. You can then link another name to that name. Both names now refer to the same object and can be used interchangeably.

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3] # create object
>>> A = mylist # point a new name to it
>>> A[0] = 99  # modify it in place
>>> mylist     # see what happens

[99, 2, 3]     # either name will change the same object
```

R does the same thing initially. But when you modify the object using one of the names, that object is then copied rather than modified in place. The other name still points to the original object. The names are no longer interchangeable.

e.g. see below. We create an object, and then point a new name to it. But in changing the object, a new copy is made in memory (because R knows there are two names pointing to it). But only the name we used to effect the change now points to the new copy. The other name still points to the original:

```
library(pryr) # get memory locations

mylist <- c(1,2,3)

pryr::address(mylist)
[1] "0x7fddbc010008" # the object is here in memory

A <- mylist
pryr::address(A)
[1] "0x7fddbc010008" # this name points to the same object

mylist[1] = 99
address(mylist)
[1] "0x7fddbb675478" # object copied to a new location

address(A)
[1] "0x7fddbc010008" # still points to the original
```

So in R, having several names that point to the same object doesn't really seem as viable as other languages where the object is modified in-place, and all names still point to the same object. *This would make it difficult to achieve what you want to do in your question.*

See this guide here for a much better explanation:

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html

Comment: When I do this it creates a new object A and then I am required to overwrite the old Somelist I had, Is there a way  I could do this with one line without overwriting Somelist entirely?  I agree that this works but is it the most efficient way to this?

Comment: It should be `mylist`, not `my list`

Comment: @yarnabrina yeah that's a minor thing, the question is the same.